# Play framework 2 : How to pass object between routes, views, and controller?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to pass a book object from views to routes, and then send it to calculate in a controller. My code is following:

**bookList.scala.html**

```
@(books: java.lang.Iterable[Book])

@main("BookList"){
    <div class="row">
        @for(book <- books.iterator()){
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail" style="height: 435px">
                         ...
                        <p><a href="@routes.Application.buy(book)" class="btn btn-primary" role="button"
                              style="vertical-align:bottom">Order now!</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>

}
```

**routes**

```
...
GET     /order                      controllers.Application.buy(book: models.Book)
...
```

However, It gave me an error : `No QueryString binder found for type models.Book. Try to implement an implicit QueryStringBindable for this type.`

I tried to change the routes as :

```
    GET     /order                      controllers.Application.buy(book)
```

It also returned an error :

```
type mismatch; found : String required: models.Book
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not how Play routing works. The Play router parses variables from the URL or query string, and converts them to native types via the `QueryBindable` typeclass. You should have something more like this:

**routes**

```
GET /order/:bookid           controllers.Application.buy(bookid: String)
```

And the action should be like:

**Application.scala**

```
def buy(bookid: String) = Action { request =>
    // Look up book by id here.
   Ok(views.html.thanks("you bought a book!"))
}
```

And the template like this:

**bookList.scala.html**

```
@for(book <- books.iterator()) {
    ...
    <a href="@routes.Application.buy(book.id)" class="btn btn-primary"         
}
```

Of course if your model's ID is other than `String` you need to modify the route's param type

**Update -- alternative using form/POST**

A form with a POST method is a better solution, or the user will buy another book each time they click the URL, and the id will be exposed. Check out the [forms](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaForms) documentation. Your template would be like this:

```
@for(book <- books.iterator()) {
    ...
    <form method="post">
      <div>@book.name</div>
      <input type="hidden" value="@book.id"/><button type="submit">buy</button>
    </form>
}
```

Comment: just for parametrized routes it's better use `@routes.Application.buy(book.id)`

Comment: Does that work? I haven't tried it, but I don't see an `apply` method on `play.api.mvc.Call`.

Comment: Of course it works, what's more important it's also type safe

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out! I thought routes.Application.buy was an instance of Call, it's actually a method returning a Call. I fixed my answer.

Comment: @RichardClose Thanks for your response. In your response, you mentioned about passing the id. Is it possible to pass a book object instead of book's id? Moreover, if I don't want to show up the book'id in the URL. What should I do in that case?

Comment: @LVarayut `Book` is a scala (or maybe java) object, it can't exist in a web page. I agree that it's better not to have the book id in the URL. Better to put the book name in a form (with POST method), and put the book id in a hidden input. I'll add to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can't simple pass object (bean) as a url query parameter.

Default you can only define simple types as a parameter types. Please read carefully play's rounting documentation -> http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaRouting especially **Parameter types**

But play framework has possibility to "learn" how to interpret specific url to bean.
You get info about this in error witch you posted. Responsible for this **QueryStringBindable** -> http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/api/java/play/mvc/QueryStringBindable.html

In short like in documentation, when you define class like this:

```java
class Book implements QueryStringBindable<Book> {
     public String title;
     public int numpages;

     public Option<Pager> bind(String key, Map<String, String[]> data) {
         if (data.contains(key + ".title" && data.contains(key + ".numpages") {
             try {
                 title = data.get(key + ".title")[0];
                 numpages = Integer.parseInt(data.get(key + ".numpages")[0]);
                 return Some(this);
             } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                 return None();
             }
         } else {
             return None();
         }
     }

     public String unbind(String key) {
         return key + ".title=" + title + "&" + key + ".numpages=" + numpages;
     }

     public String javascriptUnbind() {
         return "function(k,v) {\n" +
             "    return encodeURIComponent(k+'.title')+'='+v.title+'&'+encodeURIComponent(k+'.numpages')+'='+v.numpages;\n" +
             "}";
     }
 }
```

Then you can define route like:

```
GET  /order     controllers.Application.buy(p: Book)
```

You can then run in your browser e.g link:

```
localhost:9000/?p.title=SomeTitle&p.numpages=235
```

And in **buy** controller you will get p parameter as a Book class instance.

I did't test this code and this is in java. But you should get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom PathBindable to automatically convert an id to a book object and pass it to buy method in controller. See [PathBindable](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.PathBindable), [another example](https://github.com/leon/play-salat/blob/master/src/main/scala/se/radley/plugin/salat/Binders.scala)

**NOTE:** I would define the PathBindable in same file as the Book model.

Comment: It's unclear how to make my type PathBindable from these links, I think a small example would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example I used to parse in UUID's using [PathBindable](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.PathBindable).

I'd rather not have to parse UUID's and ensure they're well formed in all controller/action code, so I use this at the router level. I used a UUIDP (P for param) to not pollute the UUID namespace.

## Case Class and Parser

```
case class UUIDP(key: String, value: String, uuid: UUID)

object UUIDP {
  implicit def pathBinder(implicit intBinder: PathBindable[String]) = new PathBindable[UUIDP] {

    val uuidRegex = "([0-9A-Fa-f]{8}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{12})".r

    override def bind(key: String, value: String): Either[String, UUIDP] = {

      value match {
        // sanity check, prevent errors, is this really a UUID?
        case uuidRegex(c) => {
          //error check too, binary value can be invalid
          try { Right(UUIDP(key,value,UUID.fromString(value))) }
          catch {
            case ex : IllegalArgumentException => Left("Unparsable UUID") 
          }
        }
        case _ => Left("Invalid UUID Format") 
      }
    }

    // in case we need to remove this from the request
    override def unbind(key: String, user: UUIDP): String = {
      intBinder.unbind(key, user.value)
    }
  }
}
```

## conf/routes

```
GET /items/:id @com.foo.MyController.getItem(id: UUIDP)
```

## Controller

```
def getItem(sessionId: UUIDP) = Action(parse.text) { request =>
  Ok(s"Fetching item [${sessionId.uuid}]")
}
```