# Playframework twirl (scala templates) guides

Tags: scala, templates, playframework, playframework-2.0

Good day all

*note: Play! Framework newbie here.*

I am trying to familairze myself using scala templates for a project, but cannot quite seem to get it right, nor do the examples found online always work correctly.

**Problem:**

I have to have searched for small solutions for a problem, and frequently encounter syntactical errors or the like.

I decided to search for some comprehensive guide to building Scala templates used as views, but found only fragments and pieces of code that may help.

**Documentation Provided:**

- [Play Scala Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaTemplates)

**Play provided examples:**

- [Examples in Java and Scala](https://playframework.com/download#examples)

**Variables:**

- [Declaring variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031146/declare-variable-in-a-play2-scala-template)
- [Declaring Variable 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631861/scala-template-set-variable)

**Displaying Data:**

- [Displaying data using functions](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/create-play-framework-template-functions-examples)
- [Display Items in alternating rows table with indicies](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/hEQ33y6_kSI/9pZ-RLRnRpsJ)
- [Using blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081533/play-scala-template-block-statement-html-output-syntax-with-local-variable)
- [Displaying Block Scala variables in html](https://gist.github.com/fancellu/8ff1f0f8ca2dc412892a84f71b8755be) see the use of `{` and `}`

**Passing Data / Objects:**

- [Passing objects between views and controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22832033/play-framework-2-how-to-pass-object-between-routes-views-and-controller)

**Further Reading:**

- [Play Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/hEQ33y6_kSI/h9-AVxxS8bUJ)

**Question:**

*note: I am asking this only since I have no idea how to proceed*

Is there any comprehensive guide for building Scala templates. Documented to such a degree as one would find for Play! Framework?

TL;DR Where did *you* learn / discover how to create simple to complex Play! Scala templates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Here you have pack of examples and Play seed projects:
   https://playframework.com/download#examples
2. You should look for a blogposts about play templates:

   - http://mariussoutier.com/blog/2012/04/27/play-framework-2-0-templates-part-1-parameters/
3. You should read play documentation. It isn't perfect, but very helpful.
   https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaTemplates

Comment: my sincerest apologies, I forgot about the examples. However I will be keeping this question here for future viewers as this may help others.

Answer (score 2):

I would say the templates are somehow intuitive. You write html and when you want to do some scala you should start the expression with an `@`.

When I find myself struggling with the syntax I just google "scala play twirl map" if I want to know the syntax for the `.map` (twirl is the real name of the template engine)

Besides that, the documentation under https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaTemplates should be the best resource